# Unable to write test results in existing excel using JExcelApi

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jexcelapi

I am unable to write test results in existing excel using selenium I have tried but always new sheet override my existing sheet

```
      String usernamevalidationmsg = a.findElement(By.id("UserNameRequired")).getText()

      String usernamevalidationexpected = "Email is required.";

      if (usernamevalidationmsg.equals(usernamevalidationexpected))
      {
        try
        { 
                   FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("D:\\seleniumreport.xls",true);
                   WritableWorkbook book = Workbook.createWorkbook(f);
                   WritableSheet sheet = book.getSheet(0);
                   Label l = new Label(1, 2, "Pass");
                   sheet.addCell(l);
                   book.write(); 
                   book.close(); 
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
                   e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Comment: try using getWorkbook instead of createWorkbook. read http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
   WritableWorkbook book = Workbook.createWorkbook(f);
```

try:

```
 WritableWorkbook book = Workbook.getWorkbook(File file) ;
```

Comment: WritableWorkbook book = Workbook.getWorkbook(File file) ;   what should i write in place of "File file"

Comment: Add the below before **WritableWorkbook** statement:     


                `File file = new File("D:\\seleniumreport.xls");`